# How to make datepicker in full width?

Tags: ios, swift, datepicker, storyboard, uidatepicker

I have a date-picker which is opened from a text field. The issue is on iPhone 6 or 6+, the date-picker does not appear in full width. For more clarification please see the below screenshot.

[image]

EDIT:

```
 var datePickerView  : UIDatePicker = UIDatePicker(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 240))
    datePickerView.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerMode.Date
    inputView.addSubview(datePickerView) // add date picker to UIView
    datePickerView.backgroundColor = .whiteColor()
    datePickerView.sizeToFit()
    dateTextField.inputView = datePickerView
```

Comment: how did you add it ?

Comment: Did you assign the date picker to the text field's `inputView` property? Like this: `tv.inputView = UIDatePicker()`?

Comment: Yes. I have added inputView but still same issue

Comment: Can you show us your initialization code on how you're creating the picker and adding it?

Comment: More code would be very useful.

Comment: Code is provided avove

Answer (score 1):

If your `UIDatePicker()` is programmatically created, try setting its width (and/or its containing view's width) equal to the main view's width which can be accessed with `self.view.bounds.width`.

If your `UIDatePicker()` is created in Storyboard, set its layout constraints to equal the main view's width.

Both of these actions should adjust the `UIDatePicker()`'s width to fit any iPhone.